# BarButtonItem On Toolbar

Tags: ios, xcode, interface, uibarbuttonitem

I have a toolbar at the bottom of my screen. I want to have two buttons on it, one on the left side, and one on the right. However, unlike a navigation bar, there are multiple spots that aren't on each far side of the bar, but rather they stack next to each other from the left to right.

I tried using a fixed separator, however the length doesn't stay contant (the button needs to stay on the far left while another is on the far right) as orientation and device changes. So, how would I go about keeping the buttons on each side of the toolbar no matter the orientation and device? I feel like there has to be an easier way than getting the device type and orientation and varying the length for each one.

I tried my best to explain, and I can understand if there was an issue understanding what I'm trying to say. If you need any clarification or other details, just ask!

Thanks

- Jake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separators, a fixed separator and a flexible separator. You used the wrong one; use the flexible separator!

Comment: I knew I was missing something.